# How to fill holes whose borders are broken?

Tags: image, image-processing, deep-learning

I have images like this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9VJH.png)

They have holes and the borders of these holes are not complete as you can see in the picture. I want to fill them like this:
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldwyh.png)

What is the best way to achieve this?

More examples:
[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EZaU.png)
[expected output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaVSK.png)

Comment: It would be possible if the "holes" would be fully enclosed by a border. But it looks like most of them in you example are not. In that case, how can you explicitly define the limits of the "holes"?

Comment: That's some ill-defined problem. It looks like those images are generated by subtracting binary masks!? I think, it'd be better to improve this step, maybe by eroding the part which is subtracted to maintain proper borders. Some of the gaps are too large (see example 2), the continuation of the border can't be predicted that easily, especially only using classic image processing.

Comment: @Dashadower The problem is that the holes are not fully enclosed by a border.
The masks are not generated by subtracting binary masks. 
I searched a lot and the only solution I found was to first dilate the image till the borders of these holes get complete, and then fill the holes, and in the end apply some closing. But the gap is sometimes too large and increasing the amount dilation messes the other parts of the mask.